# Add a column with interval days to series temporal data

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Supposing I have a data frame df:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='
          Date            
          03/12/2007   
          02/01/2008   
          01/02/2008   
          02/03/2008  
          ')

library(lubridate)
df$Date = as_date(dmy(df$Date))
```

How can I add a column with each row interval? 
(setting 03/12/2007 as the start time) 
The desire output table would be like this:

```
      Date        d
      03/12/2007  0
      02/01/2008  30
      01/02/2008  60
      02/03/2008  90
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$d <- df$Date - min(df$Date)
```

This doesn't require the dates to be in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a workaround could be:

```
df %>% mutate(dx=c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(diff(Date)))))
```